# How can I change custom item in ListView

Tags: listview, javafx-2, listviewitem

JavaFX - I have a class Record with a method(and other functionality) `public String getName()`. I have `ListView<Record> listview` and here is the code to display `Record`'s name:

```java
listview.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Record>, ListCell<Record>>() {
    public ListCell<Record> call(ListView<Record> param) {
        final ListCell<Record> cell = new ListCell<Record>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Record item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item.getName());
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Unfortunatelly if I change the `Record`'s name like this:

```java
Record record = listview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
record.setName("New Name");
```

the cell text does not change in listview. What should I do to fix this? Or how can I change the text of the cell differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (or most JavaFX-ish) way to do this is to have the Record class' name exposed as a property and binding the textProperty of the ListCell to it. Assuming your Record has a method `nameProperty()` returning an instance of `StringPropery`, you could replace the line

```
setText(item.getName());
```

with

```
textProperty().bind(item.nameProperty());
```